# Jacobian matrix and Taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

Let $\mathbf{W}(\alpha)$ be a matrix which depends to parameter $\alpha$ and let $\mathbf{f}$ be a vector. I want to approximate $\mathbf{W}(\alpha+\Delta \alpha)\mathbf{f}$ using Taylor expansion.

My work:

- First method:

$$ \mathbf{W}(\alpha+\Delta \alpha)\mathbf{f} \approx \bigg[\mathbf{W}(\alpha)+\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)}(\alpha)\Delta \alpha\bigg]\mathbf{f} $$

$$= \mathbf{W}(\alpha)\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)}(\alpha)\Delta \alpha\mathbf{f} $$

- Second method:
  $$ \mathbf{W}(\alpha+\Delta \alpha)\mathbf{f} \approx \mathbf{W}(\alpha)\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)\mathbf{f}}(\alpha, \mathbf{f})\Delta \alpha $$

where $\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)}(\alpha)$ is Jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{W}(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)\mathbf{f}}(\alpha, \mathbf{f})$ is Jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{W}(\alpha)\mathbf{f}$ with respect to $\alpha$.

My questions: 
Are both methods correct? 
Is there any preferences to choosing one of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, both methods are correct. What you're seeing is that
$$J_{W(\alpha)f}(\alpha, f) = J_{W(\alpha)}(\alpha)f.$$

It's hard to say if one method is *better* than the other, since they are so very similar; one difference is that in the first method, you have to compute the Jacobian of a matrix-valued quantity, and in the second, of a vector-valued one; for taking scalar derivatives it doesn't much matter, but if you were differentiating with respect to, say, a vector-valued parameter, the first method would require writing down an expression involving rank three tensors, while the second would just have matrices and vectors. This comes up when differentiation rotations: calculating
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}R_\theta v$$
where $R_\theta v$ is the rotation of a vector $v$ by the axis-angle $\theta$, has a much nicer expression than the derivative $\frac{d}{d\theta}R_\theta$ of the rotation matrix itself.

By the way, if $A$ and $B$ are of any shape or size and $\odot$ is a bilinear operator,
$$d(A\odot B) = dA \odot B + A \odot dB$$
where $d$ is the differential; in the special case where $A$ is a matrix, $B$ is a vector, $\odot$ is matrix-vector multiplication, $dB=0$, and the differential is with respect to a single scalar variable $\alpha$, you recover your formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. But what if $\alpha$ be a vector, say $3\times 1$? then how $
\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)}(\alpha)\Delta \alpha\mathbf{f}
=
\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{W}(\alpha)\mathbf{f}}(\alpha, \mathbf{f})\Delta \alpha
$?

Comment: @user153245 I don't understand the question; what do you mean "how"? The equation you wrote looks correct.

Comment: Suppose $\mathbf{f}$ be a $n \times 1$ and $\alpha$ be a $3 \times 1$ vector, then $\Delta \alpha$ is a $3 \times 1$ vector too. In this case the term $\Delta \alpha \mathbf{f}$ cannot be calculated.

Comment: $J_W$ is a rank three tensor that multiplies by $\Delta \alpha$ to give a matrix, which then multiplies $f$. There is no problem. In any case if you have additional questions you should ask them in a separate post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way I asked my additional questions in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824121/calculus-of-rank-three-tensor) post. Could you maybe help me with that?