# Calculus of rank three tensor

Tags: taylor-expansion, tensor-products, tensors

Let $A(\alpha)$ be a matrix that depends to vector parameter $\alpha$. I want to approximate $A(\alpha+\Delta\alpha)$ using Taylor expansion.

My work:
$$
A(\alpha+\Delta\alpha) \approx A(\alpha)+\frac{dA}{d\alpha}\Delta\alpha
$$

Since $A$ is a matrix and $\alpha$ is a vector, I know that $\frac{dA}{d\alpha}$ is a rank three tensor. I'm not familiar with tensor and tensor calculus. I just know it looks like a 3-dimensional array.

My questions: 
 
1) How I should calculate $\frac{dA}{d\alpha}$? 
2) How I should calculate $\frac{dA}{d\alpha}\Delta\alpha$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to use indices:
$$\left(\frac{dA}{d\alpha}\Delta \alpha\right)_{ij} = \sum_k \frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial \alpha_k} \Delta \alpha_k.$$

If you really want to store $\frac{dA}{d\alpha}$ separately, as you say you can do so in a three-dimensional array, where the $ijk$ entry is e.g. $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial k}$. Multiplying by vector $\Delta \alpha$ then corresponds to taking a linear combination of "matrices slices" of $\frac{dA}{d\alpha}$, just as matrix-vector multiplication corresponds to taking a linear combination of column *vectors*.